# How can I convert the OGC WKT for Icelandic Lambert 1900 to Proj4

Tags: proj, iceland

how can I convert OGC WKT to Proj4 string

http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3052/

PROJCS["Reykjavik 1900 / Lambert 1900",GEOGCS["Reykjavik 1900",DATUM["Reykjavik_1900",SPHEROID["Danish 1876",6377019.27,300,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7051"]],TOWGS84[-28,199,5,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6657"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4657"],AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],AXIS["Longitude",EAST]],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]

Comment: Depending on PROJ.4 version you might be able to use "+axis wnu" but I'm not sure if that's at the command line level or in the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDAL knows the Reykjavik 1900 GCS, with this parameter string:

```
+proj=longlat +a=6377019.27 +b=6355762.5391 +towgs84=-28,199,5,0,0,0,0 +no_defs
```

There are no parameters given for the Lambert projection. That might be  a reason why EPSG:3052 is not implemented in Proj.4/GDAL.

The EPSG registry notes:

```
Latitude of natural origin  65° N
Longitude of natural origin 19° 1' 19.65" W
```

but no information on the projection method. It might be different from lcc and laea which are available in Proj.4/GDAL.

http://www.raunvis.hi.is/~geirf/seg/seg-ind.htm gives some hints:

"maps based on "Reykjavík 1900" datum drawn in Lambert Conformal Conic projection with one standard parallel (65° N) and the center point (x,y)=(0,0) at (65°N, 19.022°W), **x pointing West at that point and y North**."

So you can try these parameters:

```
+proj=lcc +a=6377019.27 +b=6355762.5391  +lat_1=65 +lat_0=65 +lon_0=-19.022 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +axis=wnu +towgs84=-28,199,5,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

to get this coordinate grid, displayed on a Web Mercator background:

[image]

There is an online calculator at http://cocodati.lmi.is/cocodati/cocodat-i.jsp that can transform from and to Lambert 1900. It uses a 7-parameter datum transformation, which might be better than the 3-parms that GDAL uses. The offline manual from http://cocodati.lmi.is/cocodati/cocodati-manual.pdf gives some background on this, but has a typo on the dx parameter.

So lets test with cs2cs:

```
cs2cs +proj=lcc +a=6377019.27 +b=6355762.5391  +lat_1=65 +lat_0=65 +lon_0=-19.022 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +axis=wnu +towgs84=-28,199,5,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +to +init=epsg:4326 -f "%%.8f" <Island-Lambert.txt >Island-wgs84.txt
cs2cs +proj=lcc +a=6377019.27 +b=6355762.5391  +lat_1=65 +lat_0=65 +lon_0=-19.022 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +axis=wnu +towgs84=556.020,-168.701,942.364,4.154,-0.269,-2.279,-3.729 +units=m +no_defs +to +init=epsg:4326 -f "%%.8f" <Island-Lambert.txt >>Island-wgs84.txt
cs2cs +proj=lcc +a=6377019.27 +b=6355762.5391  +lat_1=65 +lat_0=65 +lon_0=-19.022 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +axis=wnu +towgs84=556.020,-168.701,942.364,-4.154,0.269,2.279,-3.729 +units=m +no_defs +to +init=epsg:4326 -f "%%.8f" <Island-Lambert.txt >>Island-wgs84.txt
```

on a test point at `150000 -100000` which delivers:

```
-22.09304048    64.07190553 -1053.88158670
-22.09839453    64.06973810 62.39101574
-22.09264623    64.07046456 62.60636384
```

The online converter computes 
`64.070464568(N) 22.092771204(W)`
so the last parameter set fits best:

```
+proj=lcc +a=6377019.27 +b=6355762.5391  +lat_1=65 +lat_0=65 +lon_0=-19.022 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +axis=wnu +towgs84=556.020,-168.701,942.364,-4.154,0.269,2.279,-3.729 +units=m +no_defs
```

The offset is about 5 meters to the East. You might have to consider tectonic moves if you need high accuracy.

Comment: The projection method is detailed in [guidance note 7-2 - PDF](http://www.iogp.org/pubs/373-07-2.pdf) as well as in the metadata of the operation method:9826. Same as LCC (1 std parallel) but coordinates are west (positive west), north rather than east, north.

Comment: Thanks mkennedy for the guidance note 7-2 - PDF
No link to add comment to Andrej answer :) 
Thank you for your help Andrej this help me a lot

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is not possible. It should be an easy task for gdalsrsinfo http://www.gdal.org/gdalsrsinfo.html but when I saved the OGC WKT into a text file I got just an empty result.

```
gdalsrsinfo ogc_wkt.txt -o proj4

PROJ.4 : ''
```

Propably Proj.4 does not implement some parts of that coordinate system.

Comment: if it was easy then spatialreferencing.org would have done it :-)

Comment: Thanks for trying , WKT in Autocad and http://spatialreference.org/ are not the same will check this out